# Change in visa type for re-application

Tags: visas

I applied for a Chinese business visa, but the application was refused due to the invitation letter being not satisfactory. Can I apply for a tourist visa now?

Comment: You can always apply for a visa. But that says nothing about whether you would receive the visa.

Comment: What was wrong with the invitation letter? Was it genuine? Your applications need to be logically consistent. It's incredibly suspicious if you apply for a business visa to visit Shanghai for a week for business, then turn around right after a refusal and say "actually, I'd like to visit Shanghai for a week for vacation, totally a different trip, just a coincidence." It makes you look desperate to get into the country and dishonest, because a legitimate visitor doesn't keep changing the purpose of their trip.